# How to add a screenshot to allure report with python?

Tags: python, webdriver, pytest, allure

I have this code:

```
# coding: utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest
import allure


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def driver():
    _driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    yield _driver
    _driver.quit()


def test_ya(driver):
    with allure.step('open ya.ru and take screenshot'):
        driver.get('http://ya.ru/')            
        allure.attach('screenshot', driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), type='png')
```

and I try to take a screenshot and save it to allure report,
after execution I have:

```
>       with self._attachfile("%s-attachment.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), attach_type.extension)) as f:
            if isinstance(body, text_type):
E           AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extension'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For allure 2

```
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType

allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="Screenshot", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

Comment: I think the import should be `from allure import attachment_type`.

Comment: My bad. It's `from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType`

Comment: This does not work. I'm in a Behave framework so that may be the issue but after any failed steps I have the following code: `allure.attach(context.browser.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name='Screenshot', attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)` and no image file shows up on the allure report

Comment: @TuanChau i've tried every 'get_screenshot' and `save_screenshot` available. I'm debugging to make sure that my screenshot is being created but the attachment simply isn't showing up in the report. 

here's what I have at the moment: 
`allure.attach(context.browser.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(),
                      name=screen_path, attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)`

where `context.browser.driver` is referencing a Behave chromedriver that I've already declared. Also, `screen_path` is the path to the newly created image

Comment: @TuanChau where is the attached screenshot supposed to live after we run `get_screenshot_as_png`??

Comment: It's must be a byte array on memory, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of setting the `type` as a string `png`, you need to use [`allure` module attachment type constant](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/master/allure/constants.py), which is an `Enum` with `extension` attribute defined:

```
from allure.constants import AttachmentType

allure.attach('screenshot', driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

Comment: So where does this screenshot live then? Automatically in the Allure-Results directory?

Comment: Can I attach existing screenshot from some path in allure report?

Answer (score 0):

in your conftest.py add the following, make sure you already have a driver fixture as well:

[codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsXCH.png)

Comment: Hello! FYI, you can add code blocks to your answer by surrounding it with triple ` marks. That might make it a bit easier to read than looking at an image. I think there is also a way to embed images, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: No, please don't embed code image. No one could test it then.