# allure-pytest: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'attachment_type'

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, allure

I am using pytest and allure-pytest to automate my web app test cases.
My test case has below format:

```
import allure
from selenium import webdriver
class Test_Abc():

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--foreground")
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())

    def test_check_reapply_page_001(self):
        allure.attach(self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), "Failed", allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

When running test case, an error return at the allure.attach command:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'attachment_type'

Please advise me how to overcome this error?

Libs:

- allure-pytest==2.5.4
- allure-python-commons==2.5.4
- pytest==3.7.0
- selenium==3.141.0

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929416/494134 says you should be using `allure.constants.AttachmentType.PNG`.  Why are you using `allure.attachment_type.PNG`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon, I am using Allure 2. I tried with suggested codes of Tuan Chau: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47028328/7749257
`
But the below error occurs:
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
src/tests/abstract_test.py:9: in <module>
    from src.pages.abstract_page import AbstractPage
src/pages/abstract_page.py:8: in <module>
    from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
E   ImportError: No module named allure_commons.types

Comment: `import allure
from selenium import webdriver
class Test_Abc():

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--foreground")
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())

    def test_check_reapply_page_001(self):
        allure.attach(self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), "Failed", allure.attachment_type.PNG)`

The error occurs with above code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `type` [`allure` module attachment type constant](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/master/allure-python-commons/allure.py), which is an `Enum` with `extension` attribute defined.

For allure:

```
from allure.constants import AttachmentType

allure.attach('screenshot', driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

For allure 2:

```
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType

allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="Screenshot", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

**Edit:**

Have a look at [allures own attachment tests](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/master/allure-pytest/test/attachments/attachments_test.py). E.g:

```
 allure.attach(xml_body, attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.XML)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved this issue by removing allure-python-commons since this lib is conflict with others.